# ambiguous tag BDD

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, ambiguous-tags

The [bdd](/questions/tagged/bdd) tag is apparently used for

- a few questions about [Binary Decision Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) (which was the only meaning of BDD I knew until tonight),
- many more questions about [Behavior Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development) (which is what the description of the tag is about).

I suspect the questions using the first meaning have to be retagged (here are two: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738179/binary-decision-diagram) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891770/implementation-of-reduced-ordered-binary-decision-diagram-robdd)), but I have no idea of a better tag.

Is there a procedure to chose a new name, and to make sure future questions will be tagged appropriately?

**Update:**

There exists a [binary-decision-diagram](/questions/tagged/binary-decision-diagram) tag, so I have retagged the two example questions I gave using this tag.

I have scanned the 190 questions returned by a search for `[bdd] -[specflow] -[mink] -[cucumber] -[rspec] -[tdd] -[jasmine]` (the excluded tags all imply the second meaning), found only one more question with the first meaning, and fixed its tag.

If someone wants to mass-rename [bdd](/questions/tagged/bdd) as [behavior-driven-development](/questions/tagged/behavior-driven-development) to avoid confusion, I suggest to also rename [tdd](/questions/tagged/tdd) as [test-driven-development](/questions/tagged/test-driven-development) for homogeneity.

Comment: Good suggestion in re: tdd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Retag them all either [behavior-driven-development](/questions/tagged/behavior-driven-development) or [binary-decision-diagrams](/questions/tagged/binary-decision-diagrams). Tags are more useful if everyone can tell what they mean.

Once [bdd](/questions/tagged/bdd) is empty, it'll get removed and only a 1500+ rep user will be able to recreate it. It could also be burninated -- but that's probably not necessary here.

Comment: The right approach, but with 500+ questions it will take a while ;)

Comment: @ChrisF At least you don't have to worry about SO's front page as much when retagging. :)

Comment: Actually I have found a [tag:binary-decision-diagram] tag (singular), so I have retagged the two questions I pointed using this existing tag.  Searching for more...

Comment: @adl - If you can filter all 500 questions for [tag:binary-decision-diagram] stuff (as you noted, probably not as many of these as for the alternate meaning), we can instantly change all the remaining questions to [tag:behavior-driven-development] through a tag merge operation.  That should drop the workload significantly.

Comment: @KevinVermeer filtering done!  See updated question.

Comment: @adl - Nice work!  You only had to [edit 4 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/27835/adl?tab=activity#page_1-filter_revisions), though?  I would have thought that there'd be more!

Comment: @KevinVermeer Yes, it's disappointing.